# For $n\ge1$, let $S_n$ denote the group of all permutations on $n$ symbols. How to check order of elements in $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

> For $n\ge1$, let $S_n$ denote  the group of all permutations on $n$ symbols.
>
> Which of the following statements is true?
>
> A. $S_3$ has an element of order 4
>
> B. $S_4$ has an element of order 6
>
> C. $S_4$ has an element of order 5
>
> D. $S_5$ has an element of order 6

How to approach this question? Any hints?

Comment: hint: think of the elements as a multiplication of disjoint cycles.

Comment: @drhab there is no element of order $6$ in $S_4$ and order $6$ element in $S_5$ is in form $(a_1a_2)(a_3a_4a_5)$. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assertion A. is false, because $\#S_3=6$ and $4\nmid6$. For a similar reason, C. is false.

For B. and D., the approach mentioned in the comments (think of the elements as a multiplication of disjoint cycles) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! can you suggest online resources from where such question can be practiced?

Comment: @VKSingh I'm not aware of any.